# Show that if $\dim V<\infty$ then each eigenvalue of $T/U$ is an eigenvalue of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Im not totally sure that my proof is correct, can someone take a look? I will appreciate it very much.

**EDIT:** after @zipirovich pointed a mistake in the original posted proof I redone it. I hope this time this will be correct.

> Let $V$ finite dimensional and $U$ an invariant subspace of $V$ under $T\in\mathcal L(V)$. Prove that each eigenvalue of $T/U$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

The map $T/U\in\mathcal L(V/U)$ is defined as $T(x+U)=Tx+U$ for some invariant subspace $U$ of $V$ under $T$.

**Part 1:** suppose that $\lambda\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $T/U$ and $x+U$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda$, then

$$Tx+U=\lambda x+U\implies (T-\lambda)x\in U\tag{1}$$

where $x\notin U$, by the definition of eigenvalue (that is: $U$ is the zero vector on $V/U$).

By other side clearly $$x\in V\setminus U\implies \mu x\in V\setminus U\implies Tx\in V\setminus U,\quad\forall\mu\in\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}\tag{2}$$

where the last implication is the result of $\lambda x+U\neq U$. Now suppose that

$$(T-\lambda)x\in U\setminus\{0\}\tag{3}$$

and define $W$ as a subspace such that $V=U\oplus W$.

Then by $(2)$ and $(3)$ there are $w\in W\setminus\{0\}$ and $u_1,u_2\in U$ with $u_1\neq u_2$ such that $\lambda x=w+u_1$ and $Tx=w+u_2$, that is

$$(T-\lambda)x=u_2-u_1\in U\setminus\{0\}\tag{4}$$

but then

$$\lambda(w+u_2)=Tw+Tu_1\implies (T-\lambda) w=\lambda u_2-Tu_1\in U\tag{5}$$

where the RHS above is the result of $U$ being invariant under $T$.

Now because $\lambda w\in W\setminus\{0\}$ then $(T-\lambda)w\notin U\setminus\{0\}$ because $V=U\oplus W$. Hence the unique solution to the RHS in $(5)$ imply that $(T-\lambda)w=0$, so $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $T$.

**Part 2:** suppose that $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $T/U$ then exists some $x\notin U$ such that $Tx\in U$, so $T/U$ is not injective.

If $V$ is finite dimensional and $T$ is injective then $\dim T(U)=\dim U$ what imply, by the invariance of $U$ under $T$, that $T/U$ is injective. Then for $V$ finite dimensional we have that

$$T\text{ injective}\implies T/U\text{ injective}$$

then by the contrapositive we have that

$$T/U\text{ not injective}\implies T\text{ not injective}$$

so when $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $T/U$ it is also an eigenvalue of $T$.$\Box$

Comment: The claim that "$(V\setminus U)\cup\{0\}$ is a subspace of $V$" is wrong. So that's where your "proof", unfortunately, falls apart.

Comment: "Define $W$ as the subspace such that $V = U \oplus W$."  Which subspace $W$?  There are many, and there may not exist one which is $T$-invariant.

Comment: @D_S anyone will work, just choose a basis of $U$ and complete to a basis of $V$. The span of the difference is some $W$. Of course this $W$ is not necessarily $T$ invariant, indeed it is not supposed that it must be.

Comment: Can you explain more carefully how you get from $(T - \lambda)w \in U$ to $(T - \lambda)w = 0$ in (5)?

Comment: But that just says that $Tw \notin U$, doesn't it?

Comment: @T.Gunn yes, as a consequence for the unique solution possible of $(5)$.

Comment: It's not making sense. Keep in mind that you can have $x \in W$ since $x \notin U$. If this is the case then $w = \lambda x$ and in (4) you said that $(T - \lambda)x \in U \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @T.Gunn this possibility was already included, this is why $u_1,u_2\in U$, that is, is possible that $u_1=0$ so $\lambda x=w\in W\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: But then you are saying that $(T - \lambda)(\lambda x) = 0$ and $(T - \lambda)x \ne 0$. Since $\lambda \ne 0$ that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @T.Gunn yes, you are right, the proof is flawed. Thank you very much. Well, this can be a proof by contradiction of such $(3)$ cannot be.

Comment: It cannot be a proof by contradiction because (3) is entirely possible. Let $T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $U = \operatorname{span}\{e_2\}$. Then $Te_1 = e_1 + e_2 \equiv e_1 \pmod U$. So let $x = e_1, \lambda = 1$ then $(T - \lambda)x = e_2 \in U \setminus \{0\}$.